# Are view references in a query properly called "derived tables" as such?

Tags: sql-standard

While [answering a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838223/is-with-the-replacement-for-a-temp-table/14838260#14838260), I presented a definition of derived tables:

> A derived table is a complete query, inside of parentheses, that is used as if it were a real table.

But a commenter objected:

> Though there are other kinds of derived tables besides those "inside of parentheses". ... [such as] Views and Table-Valued Functions ... .

and further backed this up with:

> From the ISO/IEC 2003 Spec, section 4.3 of the Framework volume, page 13 of the August 2003 draft Spec: "An operation that references zero or more base tables and returns a table is called a query. The result of a query is called a derived table." Note that both Views and Table-Valued Functions return "the result of a query", which is a derived table. Microsoft (and to a lesser extent, Oracle) are notorious for mistakenly equating "derived table" and "sub-query" in their documentation, but Derived Tables do also include pre-defined queries like Views.

So what's the real scoop, here? Am I to relegate what I thought of as *derived tables* to simply "FROM clause aliased inline subqueries" or are views not properly *derived tables*?

Please note: I searched for quite a while online and could not find anything definitive. I don't have a copy of the said spec.

Also, I think it's worth addressing something else. Let's say that views are properly called "derived tables". Does this make the *reference* to the view also a "derived table" or merely a reference? For an example with a CTE that should drive the point home:

```
WITH SalesTotals AS (
   SELECT
      O.CustomerID,
      SalesTotal = Sum(OrderTotal)
   FROM
      dbo.CustomerOrder O
   GROUP BY
      O.CustomerID
)
SELECT
   C.Name,
   S.SalesTotal
FROM
   dbo.Customer C
   INNER JOIN SalesTotals S
      ON C.CustomerID = S.CustomerID;
```

The `SalesTotals` CTE introduced with `WITH` is a derived table. But is `INNER JOIN SalesTotals` *also* a derived table, or just a *reference* to a derived table? Does this query have two derived tables or one? If one, then by extension I think that a view may be a derived table, but referencing it may not *have* to be a derived table.

Comment: I can't find that comment on Microsoft and Oracle in the final specs (not the draft) - although I do agree that a lot of people do mix up "sub-queries" and "derived tables" - but that is not your question. The specs states later in that chapter: "*A view is a named  query, which can be invoked by use of this name. The result of such an invocation is called a viewed table*"

Answer (score 3):

From a SQL Server perspective, a *table expression* is a ***named query***. This concept of a named query seems in line with what @a_horse_with_no_name [commented on earlier](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34620/are-view-references-in-a-query-properly-called-derived-tables-as-such#comment60213_34620). There are four types of of *table expressions* which are:

- Derived Tables
- Common Table Expressions
- Views
- Inline Table-Value Functions

A **Derived Table** is a subquery that returns an entire table result.
A **CTE** is like a derived table but usually thought to be more readable and modular. It also has a recursive feature. A **View** is a reusable named query in which the definition of the table expression is stored. The primary difference between a View and an **Inline Table-Valued Function** is that the latter takes parameters whereas the former does not.

<sup>This has been compiled from the discussion on Table Expressions in Ben-Gan, et al, *Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012*, Chapter 4.</sup>

Comment: Do you have thoughts on the difference between the *definition* of a "named query" and a *reference* to a named query?

Comment: @ErikE I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're driving at. I understand the difference, but help me understand what the thoughts would address.

Comment: I guess I just wanted to know the "official" stance: would a true derived table explicated in a query always be introduced with parentheses, or would simply referring to the name of a view (itself a type of "derived table" or "named query") also be properly called "introducing a derived table to the query"? I see a difference between having the actual query contents present, or having them hidden behind a layer of abstraction (behind a name).

Comment: I'm not sure there is a difference, at least not in the minds of the authors of the book I cited. The "naming" of the table expression allows for reuse outside of the context of that batch.